# How to add a GeoWebCache gridset to all layers in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, geoserver-rest-api, gridsets

I have 300+ layers in my GeoServer layer library, I have just created a custom gridset I would like to use for all of my layers. I don't want to go through my whole library adding the gridset manually through the UI, so I have played around with the GeoServer rest API and I am able to modify layers with the following command:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d @ui_UI00000ENNR.xml  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/layers/ui:UI00000ENNR.xml"
```

And this is the contents of the ui_UI00000ENNR.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeoServerLayer>
  <id>LayerInfoImpl-288ccd00:163bb872e8d:-7ff6</id>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <inMemoryCached>true</inMemoryCached>
  <name>ui:UI00000ENNR</name>
  <mimeFormats>
    <string>image/png</string>
    <string>image/jpeg</string>
  </mimeFormats>
  <gridSubsets>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>EPSG:3857</gridSetName>
    </gridSubset>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>EPSG:4326</gridSetName>
    </gridSubset>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>EPSG:27700</gridSetName>
    </gridSubset>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>EPSG:900913</gridSetName>
    </gridSubset>
  </gridSubsets>
  <metaWidthHeight>
    <int>4</int>
    <int>4</int>
  </metaWidthHeight>
  <expireCache>0</expireCache>
  <expireClients>0</expireClients>
  <parameterFilters>
    <styleParameterFilter>
      <key>STYLES</key>
      <defaultValue></defaultValue>
    </styleParameterFilter>
  </parameterFilters>
  <gutter>0</gutter>
</GeoServerLayer>
```

My plan is to create a template xml file and then loop through my list of layers, populating the xml file and running the curl command for each layer. The only problem is I don't know the id for each layer, `<id>LayerInfoImpl-288ccd00:163bb872e8d:-7ff6</id>`, in the example above. Does anyone know how I could pull all layer names and there associated ids from GeoServer? Or is there a much quicker way of doing what I want to accomplish?

Comment: I think you can leave that ID out and GeoServer will auto populate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ian Turton said GeoServer autopopulates the ID and my method that I proposed worked.